# MongoDB function and how to call it?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to MongoDB and I found this function on the web. it's going to work for my all queries.
For settings.amount, settings.balance etc..

```
exports.updateUsers = function ( user_id, where, what, pass )  {
    var _where = 'settings.'+where; //when I use it doesn't update
    var update = {};
    update[_where] = what;
    user.findOneAndUpdate(
          {'user_id' : user_id}, 
          update).exec(function(e,d){
            pass("ok")
          })
};
```

Could anyone explain to me how can I call this query to update balance or amount?

Could anyone give me an example of updating something?

Comment: You just have to import this where you want and call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
const { updateUsers } = require('./pathToFile.js'); // add the correct path;
// assuming you want to update the balance of a user to 69
updateUsers('some id', 'balance', 69, (result) => { 
 if(result === 'ok') {
  // do something
 } else if(result === 'bad') {
  // you have an error
 }
})
```

I would also change `updateUsers` to handle errors:

```
exports.updateUsers = function (user_id, where, what, pass) {
    var _where = 'settings.' + where; //when I use it doesn't update
    var update = {};
    update[_where] = what;
    user.findOneAndUpdate(
        { 'user_id': user_id },
        update).exec(function (error, d) {
            if (!error) {
                pass('ok');
            } else {
                pass('bad')
            }
        })
};
```

Comment: Is this could call in mongo shell?

Comment: @rra No this is something you would do in a node.js app

Comment: @rra You can write the equivalent of this to run in the shell. See [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)